# Where can I find records of a telephone call between Cisco & Kissinger in October 1973?

Tags: research

I read [*Price Wars* by Rupert Russell](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/57925998-price-wars) and he references

> 'We have to get the bloody Saudi [ambassador] in': Telecon, Cisco/Kissinger 11 October 1973

A simple Google search turned up a 11 Oct 1973 Telecon between Nixon & Kissinger, but I can't find one for Cisco/[Kissinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Kissinger)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Who is "Cisco"? Presumably we're not talking about the captain of DS9, or the hip-hop artist? Perhaps the pulp western hero Cisco Kid? Anyone asking Google this question is just going to come up with the internet router company.

Comment: POTUS calls are all (supposed to be) logged. I don't think the same nessecarily goes for Secretaries of State, so this info may not be available. Are there any relevant footnotes or endnotes in that book that might give us a hint here?

Comment: [Joseph J Sisco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_J._Sisco)

Comment: @justCal that should be an answer!  Good job

Comment: All that link answers/indicates is that the entire statement might be in err if the writer involved couldn't even get the name of one of the principals involved correct...

Comment: I've been going through some state department papers involving Sisco [here](https://history.state.gov/historicaldocuments/frus1969-76v25/d148) but have been unable to find the reported conversation. Most of these papers are minutes of meetings however, so only record phone conversations if they occurred during a meeting.

Comment: @justCal - I'm certainly not on firm enough ground to gig anyone on spelling, but it would seem reasonable to hold back on putting a lot of effort into this until such time as the OQ can answer the question about any foot/end notes the book itself may have on the matter.  That could save everyone a ton of work.

Comment: You can read the relevant portions of the book in a ['look inside' at amazon](https://www.amazon.com/Price-Wars-Commodities-Markets-Chaotic/dp/0385545851?asin=0385545851&revisionId=&format=4&depth=1). The part the OP listed *is* the footnote, the actual section is on page 216.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the name.  The original book was shit, so...   The the ambassador in that reference is a relation and I'd like to learn more